# Installing phpMyAdmin installs Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

When I install phpMyAdmin it automatically installs Apache. That happens even though I do not select Apache in the installation process of phpMyAdmin and choose not to install via db-config.

How do I avoid to install Apache since I am using Nginx?

My setup is:
- Debian Squeeze
- dotdeb.org setup in sources.list
- nginx 1.0.11
- PHP 5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apt-get has a download only option. So do the `sudo apt-get install -d phpmyadmin` and then choose the packages you want to install and install them manually with `sudo dpkg -i <packages>.deb`  These packages are usually downloaded to `/var/cache/apt/archives/` .

Answer (score 0):

What OS do you use?If it is using packages like Debian or Redhat, Apache  is installed as dependency since PHPadmin requires webserver.Consult your OS documentation for details how to ignore dependencies.

Comment: Check this howtoforge article that may help: http://www.howtoforge.com/running-phpmyadmin-on-nginx-lemp-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.04

Comment: howtoforge do not take into account the Apache get's install. And the webserver nginx is already installed